# Magento - Select some customer infos

Tags: magento

for the purpose of a module that I began to realize, I want to make a select query which gives me the address, name and surname of one or more clients.

I am a bit lost in the database magento, Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo out each select magento does with getSelect() method.

for one client

`echo Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load('id')->getSelect();`

or whole collection

`echo Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->getSelect();`

Comment: with : 
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('postcode', '70184');
I have this error :
Fatal error: Call to a member function isStatic() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php on line 372

Comment: I actually have not tested this :) but the thing is that customer has addresses (shipping and billing) so you need to query address collection and join user information or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You must search the tables **customer_entity** and **customer_address_entity**

Comment: yes, I know that, but when I specify, to select for example the customer that have zip code : 70184 ?? 
How can I do that ?